# Why are table aliases not compiled out of existence when sharing SQL statements (on Oracle DBMS)

Tags: sql, oracle

Quest Software\Knowledge Xpert states:

If two identical SQL statements vary because an identical table has two different aliases, then the SQL is different and will not be shared.

What sense does this make?

I understand that if I have table A and table B and I fail to alias an ambiguous column what I'm trying to do is mathematically ambiguous, but the names of the aliases themselves shouldn't matter should they?  Why would SQL/Oracle care that table A's alias is FOO in one statement and BAR in another when determining for caching purposes if they are identical?

On a similar line why should whitespace or word case matter at all?

"SQL cannot be shared within the SGA unless it is absolutely identical. Statement components that must be the same include:

Word case (uppercase and lowercase characters)
 
Whitespace
 
Underlying schema objects"

Underlying schema objects makes sense, because after all mathematically that's something different.  Is the idea I might be an idiot and have columns named "Foo" "FOO" and "foo" and we don't want to accidentally cache?

Comment: The cache returns the column names.  Names with different capitalization are different, so the queries are different.

Comment: Technically the table aliases make no difference to the semantics of the queries, but in practice generally you wouldn't have two identical statements that differ only in table aliases - so this optimisation would be of limited benefit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this restrictions are due to SQL processing mechanism Oracle uses. It calculates hash value of query text and if this hash matches with one stored in SGA it helps to avoid hard parsing steps. More details are [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e15858/tgsql_sqlproc.htm#TGSQL175).

Answer (score 4):

I think it's to avoid the extra overhead of "normalizing" each SQL statement before creating a SQL_ID.

The SQL_ID is a hash of the SQL statement. In order to do what you are asking, it would require the SQL parser to do extra work (for limited benefit) in order to make a uniform SQL statement that would compare exactly with another statement that was equivalent, but had mixed case, extra spaces, etc.

Comment: I think it's more about making the parsing of SQL more efficient.  There are a huge number of parses taking place in a typical production system. Shaving a little bit of time off of each parse speeds the whole system up.  I'm certain it could be done if there were enough of a demand for it.

Comment: To me it was just unexpected behavior.  I sort of expected more precise handling of the statements.